# PHP Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in Mongo DB and Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am having the following error

ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Cannot use object of type stdClassàK´cðËÛ as array

Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (the above one is the exact line from my browser).

while I am running a codeigniter script with MongoDB database on Amazon EC2 instance. Same code is working for different amazon instance but while I am moving these codes into a new instance I am having this issue. Is it I am missing some installation (any sort of PHP library) or anything. I am also using Alex Bible's MongoQB. Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: The full stack trace and file/line of the exception would be helpful, or a minimal code example that triggers the error. Versions of the libraries you are using are also helpful. It's not clear from  your post what the context of this error is.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following in my MongoDb config file.

```php
$config['mongo_return'] = 'array';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily cast an `stdClass` object to array, since it is just a container.

```
$array = (array) $object ;
```